# member login using photo

Tags: comments

I'm new in WordPress
what I want is my website only can be opened by who was invited by me..
and but I want using an image as my invitation,, not mere a link..
so the image is used to login password
but I want to member's comments also connected to their Facebook and or twitter account

I will create just 5 to 6 pages of my web
one of them a different to each member
the rest is completely same

and the last is I want to before the members logout they have to give a comments
they cannot even close the tabs or browser
:smile

P.S. this is will be my wedding web
so i hope they give me a comment about me b4 they leave

Comment: This is a multi-question post. The "image as my invitation" goal is not clear. And I don't think blocking a user from closing a browser tab or a window is doable.

Comment: sori
idk if multi-q is forbiden
:)

i ll send my members an image
then they ll use it to login to my web

ok
at least can i give alert b4 they go??

Comment: It's not exactly forbidden, but your scope has to be narrow. Asking a good question will bring you good answers. Check the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). You have: 1) Custom email for new user registration -  2) Comments connected to social media - 3) Warn before closing browser tab or window. This last one doesn't belong to this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plugin like [SB Welcome Email Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/welcome-email-editor/) to edit the welcome message. You can use HTML here, so adding an image is easy.

To make sure only invited members can see the site untick the *Anyone can register* setting on `wp-admin/options-general.php` and install a plugin like [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) to require users to log in before they can see anything.

For your other questions … [ask new, separate questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Be aware that questions about browser behavior are off topic here. ;)

Comment: thanks 4 ur answer

but i think SB welcome email is not what i look 4
the topic is about HOW TO LOGIN BY UPLOADING AN IMAGE.. not how i ll distribute that image..
:)

ok
i ll search last topic in google anyway
thanks

Comment: @qzxi _I want using an image as my invitation_ – that's not about uploading anything!?

Comment: image is used to login password

sorry 4 my bad english

its simply how to using image as password to login my web

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that has to be done to "login with an image" is to change the way the login system works. The default method is POST but in this instance you will need GET Variables to pass the username and password via a url pretty much. This isn't recommended at all but if you did something such as: (add this code to your Functions.php)

```
add_action('init', 'GET_login');
function GET_login() {
    if(in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php'))):
        if(isset($_GET['log']) && isset($_GET['pwd'])):
            $creds = array();
            $creds['user_login'] = $_GET['log'];
            $creds['user_password'] = $_GET['pwd'];
            $creds['remember'] = true;     
            $redirect_to = admin_url('profile.php');
            $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
            if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
            }else{  
                $redirect_to = admin_url('profile.php');
                wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
            exit();
            }
        endif;
    endif;
}
```

You can now login using this type of URL: 
 `http://example.com/wp-login.php?log=username&pwd=password`
With this type of URL Structure you can generate a QR image here -> [QR Image Generator](https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/qr/)

using your website link with the embedded login. Now everyone on the website can login using a QR Reader for Personalized QR IMAGES that you can send out!

Example QR Image 
[image: Example QR Image]

WARNING: If anyone visits that GET login page in a browser with the Google Toolbar, its highly possible to get the logins indexed by google. Just a heads up. Best way to login with GET should be with IP specific hashes, not plain data.

Anyhow you should be able to build off this!